# How to draw lines perpendiculr to the circular arcs in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

In our camera systems, images are collected for operators to examine the surfaces on our parts.

In this example, we need to examine the interior surface of a cone where the images are taken for every rotation of certain degrees.

We want to find the center of this big ring or fan area to further determine the region of interest.

Then we'd like to first draw two lines perpendicular to the circular arcs to find the center of the cone.

How could we draw such lines.

[image]

Raw sample image:
[image]

Comment: You didn't show what you have tried so far. You could try to preprocess the images for a circle detection using `cv::HoughCircle`. The center is stored during this process. Then, you could detect your most outer ring with and draw lines connecting the center of the circle to your outer ring.

Comment: Now I think it's easier to draw two vertical bisectors and find the intersection point.